# Is it possible to select data from Cassandra only for specific timeframe?

Tags: database, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Let's assume I store data in Cassandra where one column has a timestamp format and it is also a key by which I can select data based on datetime ranges. My data has frequency of 1 minute, therefore retrieving rows for the entire day will get me 1440 data points. But for some applications I would like to retrieve only 24 points per day at each even hour.

Is it possible to make a query in CQL that will get me data points only for even hours or for every certain amount of time like 15 or 30 minutes?

My cassandra version:

`[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.10 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]`

EDIT: I have designed the table but I can change it if needed. So far the query to create the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE sensors_test 
(name text, 
value double, 
time timestamp, 
PRIMARY KEY (name, time) 
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC);
```

Comment: have you designed any table, please mention that in question statement.

Comment: @Gunwant question edited to contain more information about the tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your design will serve the purpose, but it will create wide row.

```
CREATE TABLE sensors_test 
( name text,
  year  int,
  month int,
  day int,
  hour int,
  value double, 
  time timestamp, 
  PRIMARY KEY ((name,year,month,day,hour), time) 
 ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC);
```

This table design will solve the wide row problem. You can fetch data for any hour of the day, also you can use range query on time column.